# RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider.mm Build input file cannot be found React native

Tags: reactjs, native

My app was working and all of the sudden I started getting this error when I try building with Xcode:

> Build input file cannot be found '…/RCTThirdPartyFabricComponentsProvider.mm'

I cleaned the **build folder**, deleted **Derived data** content and I am still having the same issue.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Same here, I still have no ideia why this is happening

Answer (score 3):

Apperly it was a bug in React Native that was already fixed, so we just need to wait until next update or try the beta/alphas versions
-> [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/f4dbd15f0bb089e48db9e7aafb4d6bcd73684d61)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue wit the next steps:

1. Close Xcode.
2. In your console in the root project:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

3. In the ios folder, open the xcworkspace file.
4. Clean the project in Xcode
5. Run. The issue should gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after enabling the new architecture with turbo modules. In my case, cleaning the build folder helped to fix the problem. Using React Native v0.73.0.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the latest version of Reanimated, add this in babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```